# Automate fetching images from folders and place them in html file on load

Tags: jquery, html, image, automation

I'm creating a new website for a photographer who has a large portfolio and updates it frequently. I want to automate the proces of adding images to the html files on load so I don't anymore need to manually add images to the html file.

In pseudo code:

> 1. On page load, fetch all images from /images/portfolio/thumbs and place them in div 'x'
> 2. Give 'm all 'data-full="[image file name]"'
> 3. Give 'm all 'width="300"'
> 4. Place them within an anchor

It would show all thumbs and I'm using a special lightbox plugin that shows the larger version on click *(which requires the data attribute)*.

First of all: Is this achievable? and secondly: Does this decrease web performance, instead of manually writing all images in the .html file?

Comment: Need to use server language to read directories (or database) and create the output.

Comment: Difficult? I wouldn't mind PHP, even though I can't write a single line of php.

Comment: No, not difficult in php. Can use [glob()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) to create array, then loop over array to generate either json or html

Answer (score 0):

Javascript will not allow the user to use direct access to files on your hard disk
try to add apache server and add your images name into a table in a Mysql data base
then you can do dynamic call using php script for your images easily

Comment: Uhm. Of course the site, language, should read the directories on the apache server, not on my local hard disk. I want to automate the proces that much that I only need to add images to the apache website directory, instead of that plus adding <img src=".."> to the html sheet, every day.

Comment: I did this in a project of mine using php, ajax call (javascript) as following
1- select all the names of the picture from database
2-make an array containing the images' name
3- do json_encode for this array and echo it
4- on client side make loop on that array and append each time your proper tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use python for this:

```
import os

with open("all.html", "w") as a:
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(r'C:\Users\[user]\Folder'):
   for filename in files:
     f = os.path.join(path, filename)
     a.write("<img src=\"" + str(f) + "\" /^>" + os.linesep)
```

I've used this successfully to create jpg based html files from any folder of choice.